# How many ATP molecules are formed?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, homework, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

What is the number of ATP molecules formed during the photosynthetic processes which consume 8 molecules of $\text{H}_2\text{O}$ due to noncyclic electron transport and subsequent photophosphorylation?

Assume that quinone cycle facilitates the transfer 4H<sup>+</sup> to the lumen of thylakoid membrane for every two electrons passing through electron transport system and one ATP is formed for every 3H<sup>+</sup> moving down the proton gradient by the mediation of F<sub>0</sub>F<sub>1</sub>-ATPase

**MY ATTEMPT**: In the lumen, due to hydrolysis 16 H<sup>+</sup> are formed. Due to quinone cycle 32 H<sup>+</sup> are taken from stroma and transferred to the lumen and NADP<sup>+</sup> takes 48 H<sup>+</sup> so in stroma there is deficiency of 80 and there are only 48 H<sup>+</sup> in the lumen. If I assume that if there were initially hundred H<sup>+</sup> on both sides then after non cyclic transport inside the lumen there are 148 H<sup>+</sup> and in stroma there are 20 H<sup>+</sup> so to have equilibrium then there should be 84 H<sup>+</sup> on both side so total 64 H<sup>+</sup> should travel then I am getting 64/3 ATP which is wrong. **Where I am going wrong?**

Screenshot of question paper [image]

Comment: I had attempted but iam getting 64/3 ATP as answer which is wrong.

Comment: I have no knowledge in photophosphorylation, but isn't ATP synthase creates 3 ATP for every 10 H+? and so maybe it's 64/3.3 ATP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: diagram for non-cyclic photophosphorylation from "Pradeep's: A textbook of Biology for Class XI]

Sorry for the poor quality of the image, but its just as a reference for my answer.

You have made the question too complex. From the figure, we find that 1 H<sub>2</sub>O gives 2 H<sup>+</sup> and 2 e<sup>-</sup>. 2 e<sup>-</sup>, through quinone cycle, provide 4 H<sup>+</sup> i.e. total 6 H<sup>+</sup> which form 6/3 = 2 ATP i.e.

1 H<sub>2</sub>O => 6 H<sup>+</sup> => 2 ATP

Multiply this equation by 8 and you get:

8 H<sub>2</sub>O => 48 H<sup>+</sup> => 16 ATP

So, 16 ATP should be the answer.

**Reference**:

Pradeep's: A textbook of Biology for Class XI, 2015, Vol. II, page IV/106

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35553/discussion-between-jm97-and-aayush-srivastav).

Comment: I threw an answer up, but according to my calculation, and ignoring ATP from NADPH, 16 ATP should be correct. I upvoted this.

Comment: @JM97 is it okay now?

Comment: @aayush Srivastav in your answer you are not considering the fact that reduction of NADP to NADPH is causing a deficiency of protons which effects the proton gradient

Comment: @JM97 I don't think that considering H+ gradient from NADP+ reduction is important because your question does not say to consider it (like the 4 H+ from Q cycle). Also, considering it is not only out of the scope of question (as said by @Kendall) but also it will always give a value in fraction.

Comment: So if we do not consider the role of NADP then only 40 protons must travel so only 40/3 ATP ARE GENERATED

Comment: I don't know whether its important to maintain H+ equilibrium inside & outside thylakoid. I have only studied that each proton delivered inside thylakoid builds up a proton gradient, so each of those protons should be removed from inside.

Comment: Think about this one: you have 100 H+ inside & outside. By splitting 2 H2O, you get 12 H+ more inside and 10 H+ less outside i.e. 112 inside and 90 outside. So, to have equilibrium there should be 101 H+ on each side i.e. 11 H+ should travel out, giving 11/3 ATP, which is obviously wrong as 4 ATP are actually produced.

Comment: That is the real question which I was really asking, WHY DONT WE APPLY PRICIPLES OF CHEMISTRY IN THIS PROCESS?

Comment: Now if that is your real question, then I think you should edit your question or ask another question which clearly states your problem, and maybe you will get better answers in chemistry SE (I'm just guessing).

Answer (score 2):

**I think we can look at it like this**
[image]

Your noncyclic pathway liberates 4H<sup>+</sup> from two water molecules. We're doing that because to get one O<sub>2</sub>, you've got to split 2H<sub>2</sub>O. This happens in photosystem II. So in the next step (you know, really broadly) the electrons are passed to cytochrome b<sub>6-f</sub> complex, where each electron allows it to pump 2H<sup>+</sup> into the thylakoid space. Since we got 4e<sup>-</sup> from splitting 2H<sub>2</sub>O, from that we can get 8H<sup>+</sup>. So net H<sup>+</sup> = 8 + 4 or 12H<sup>+</sup>/O<sub>2</sub>, or we can rewrite it as 4ATP/O<sub>2</sub>.

For 2H<sub>2</sub>O you also got 2NADPH, which can also be used to get ATP. I think it's 3ATP/NADPH, so you get  (6+4)ATP/2H<sub>2</sub>O and repeat four times:

**8H<sub>2</sub>O = 40ATP**

Ignoring NADPH oxidation:

**8H<sub>2</sub>O = 16ATP**

Comment: please see the z scheme given at Wikipedia yours is different , according to Wikipedia only 2e are needed for reduction of NADP to NADPH but according to yours 4e are reducing 2NADP, SO WHICH ONE IS CORRECT?

Comment: The reduction of NADP to NADPH requires two electrons *per* NADPH produced, [diagram](http://previews.123rf.com/images/logos2012/logos20121404/logos2012140400057/27906122-Illustration-of-NADP-redox-reaction-with-chemical-formulas-with-marked-variable-fragments-vector-iso-Stock-Vector.jpg). So, either representation is correct, but I utilize 4e > 2NADPH because the light reactions don't just release radical oxygen, they release O2, hence I always begin with 2H2O. @JM97

Comment: why don't you consider the fact that reduction of NADP to NADPH also contributes to proton gradient

Comment: Because you specified noncyclic electron transport.

Comment: reconsidering it again from starting then 8 water molecules gives 16 protons and 16e then first inside thylakoid lumen there is an increase of 16H+ second quinone cycle facilitates transfer of 32H+ from stroma to lumen so there is decrease of proton of stroma and increase of protons in lumen. Third 16e will reduce only 8NADP to 8NADPH so there is decrease of only 8e on stroma. Overall:inside lumen +48 , in stroma -40 so to get equilibrium as per chemistry principles only 44H+ should pass therefore we get 44/3 ATP.

Comment: do you want to say that in non cyclic electron transport there is no role of reduction of NADP to NADPH in creating proton gradient? If I follow your assumption then also 48 H+ all will not be transferred only  40H+ will transport so that in equilibrium on both sides so that there will be 8H+ on both sides

Comment: The NADP *does* play a role in the proton gradient, but it's outside the scope of the textbook question. To be specific, though, the concentration of protons in the lumen is higher than the stroma. So you would expect more H+ in the lumen than the stroma.

Answer (score 0):

As we know that for 4 H²O molecules one non cyclic electron transport occur which gives us 4H+ ions ..this 4H+ ions gives 2 ATP so 8H+ ions will gives us 4 ATP....so
Ans= 4ATP molecules /8H+ ions

Answer (score -2):

ACCORDING TO ME THE ANSWER IS 24 ATP THAT IS BECAUSE
8H+ IS PRODUCE DE TO PHOTOLYSIS.
16 H+ WILL BE TRANSFERRED INTO LUMEN.
SO **8 ATP** WILL BE PRODUCE BY ATPASE {TOTAL 24 H+]
4 NADPH2 WILL PRODUCE **12 ATP**
**4 ATP** WILL BE RELEASED FROM ELECTRON WHILE MOVING IN PS1.
SO TOTAL 8+12+4 = *24 ATP.*

Comment: First: Please don't write in all caps as this is seen as yelling. And then it would be nice to show some references.