# Why it seems that principles of chemistry are not being applied in this biochemical process?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

[image]According to an answer in [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42413/how-many-atp-are-formed), my concept used below does not apply:

In the non-cyclic photophosphorylation, consider splitting of two water molecules, then 4 e<sup>-</sup> (electrons) and 4 H<sup>+</sup> (protons) are generated in the lumen of the thylakoid. Due to quinone cycle 8 H<sup>+</sup> are transferred from stroma to lumen. 4 e<sup>-</sup> will reduce 2 NADP<sup>+</sup> to 2 NADPH, these H<sup>+</sup> are taken from stroma so there is a net decrease of 8 + 2 = 10 H<sup>+</sup> and a net increase of 4 + 8 = 12 H<sup>+</sup> in the lumen. So if we apply principles of chemistry then to attain equilibrium there should be equal number of H<sup>+</sup> on both side. Therefore 11 H<sup>+</sup> must be transferred from lumen of thylakoid to stroma. Now there is 1 H<sup>+</sup> on each side at equilibrium. We know that F<sub>0</sub>-F<sub>1</sub> ATPase will produce 1 ATP for 3 H<sup>+</sup> being transferred so in this process 11/3 ATP should produce but in books it is given that all 12 H<sup>+</sup> are transported which is violating the principle of chemical equilibrium and produces 12/3=4 ATP.

So I basically want to ask: **Why does it seem that in this process the principles of chemistry are violated?**

Comment: About which principles of chemistry are you talking?

Comment: @chris According to books all 12p will get transferred but we know from chemistry point of view that only 11p could get transferred as per the gradient created

Comment: @Chris the principle is that at equilibrium there must equal number of protons on both sides

Comment: A schematic of the reactions involved would help. It's kind of a narrative.

Comment: You should just write down the equation. [Here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) is an explanation on how to write chemistry expression. Then, you'll probably want to use the term [stoichiometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoichiometry) somewhere in your post. Finally, note that your question would be a better fit for Chemistry.SE than for Biology.SE but I would predict that the level of knowledge in chemistry needed to answer the question will be simple enough for us, biologists.

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22519/ I think this answers the question, but let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the link given by @Kendall

> Such a gradient can be maintained because the thylakoid membrane is essentially impermeable to protons.

I think this solves your dilemma of 'why not maintaining equilibrium' totally.

> The reason for this difference is that the thylakoid membrane is quite permeable to Cl- and Mg2+. The light-induced transfer of H+ into the thylakoid space is accompanied by the transfer of either Cl- in the same direction or Mg2+ (1 Mg2+ per 2 H+) in the opposite direction. Consequently, electrical neutrality is maintained and no membrane potential is generated.

It precisely shows why electrical equilibrium is not disturbed due to pH disturbance.

Finally:

> 2 H<sub>2</sub>O + 2 NADP<sup>+</sup> + 10 H<sup>+</sup><sub>stroma</sub> => O<sub>2</sub> + 2NADPH + 12 H<sup>+</sup><sub>lumen</sub>
>
> 12 H<sup>+</sup><sub>lumen</sub> + 4 ADP + 4 P<sub>i</sub> => 4 ATP + 12 H<sup>+</sup><sub>stroma</sub>